Black and white Sci Fi 50s-60s with female alien
I'm looking for the title of a Sci Fi film, circa late 50s, early 60s, black and white, with a female alien on board a space craft. 
She is humanoid, clad in a sparkly, form-fitting suit that covers her body except her face. 
I believe she "impregnates" some of the crew with her alien life form. I also recall a crew member displaying an x-ray of his chest with the alien life forms in his chest cavity.  
I saw this film when I was 8 or 9 years old, in the early 60s, and can't help thinking it may have inspired some elements of Alien.

That seems a little erm.. risque for a B&W 50's movie. A woman impregnating a man!

DVers should explain why they're DVing so the OP can address their concerns...  Being risque (for the time of its release) doesn't make it off-topic, and the question seems otherwise well-formed to me.  Don't DV just because you think it's difficult to answer - that's what SE is here for!

@Steve-O They're not close voting because it's risque...it's missing some essential details (Language / Country for instance)...perhaps some descriptions of the actors. Unfortunately a movie seen by a child 50 years ago is likely to be conflated with many others. I merely commented as the concept of a 50s B&W movie having a woman, even an alien one, impregnate a man seems remarkably outside the norm.

The outfit made me think of The Astounding She-Monster (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050143/), but not the plot.
